# Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node. while appending to new element

Tags: javascript, node.js

HI i am a newbie to web development.

i am getting above error. i want to attach href attribute tag to image tag and my code is

```
function linkus()
    {
        var a= document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var b=document.createElement("a");
        b.href="";
        b.rel="prettyPhoto";
        b.appendChild(a[0]);
    }
```

any help please...

Comment: Did you check to see how many elements were found? If there are none, then `a[0]` will be `undefined`. So use `console.log()` to examine your values, like `console.log(a[0])` or `console.log(a.length)`

Comment: When palacing b.appendChild(a[0]);  my website is not displaying properly and when removing a[0] the above error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the a[0] is not a node. Which is your HTML code?

With this example it works.

With the 'cloneNode' it double the node!

Without it, it move the node!

```js
function linkus()
    {
        var a= document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var b=document.createElement("a");
        b.href="";
        b.rel="prettyPhoto";
      
        if (a.length > 0){
            // copy it 
            var new_node = a[0].cloneNode(true);
            // append to the b element 
            b.appendChild(new_node);
            // append the b element to the doc
            document.body.appendChild(b);
        }
        else{
            console.error("No img node found!");
        }
    }
// call the fuction
linkus();
```

```html
<!-- without at least a img node in the  HTML code it gives that error -->
<img src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mirko. it was entering into if condition but not attaching the tag to my <img> tag

Comment: And its not giving any error but it also not attaching tag

Comment: what error it gives you?  i modified the code with the 'cloneNode' function, it that the desire effect?

Comment: hi Mirko. The above code is not disturbing design works of site but still not attaching tag to my image tag.                                                                                     Here i am  using gallery slideshow and i want present the images in a lightbox so i am trying to attach a href attribute tag so onclick of image it will show image in lightbox.     any help please...